# Chartjs-node-canvas heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, chart.js

I am running this code in a NodeJS Server. The idea is to create charts to insert in PDF with PDFMake.

Stress Testing it, reaches Heap Out of Memory.

So, I wonder if there is a way of configuring the NodeJS API to avoid this problem.
Or improving the code...

```js
   let chartJSNodeCanvas = new ChartJSNodeCanvas({ width: 800, height: 600 }); 
    
    Chart.defaults.animation = false;
    Chart.defaults.responsive = false;

    const chartBody: ChartConfiguration = req.body['chart'];
    const width: number = req.body['pageWidth'];
    const height: number = req.body['pageHeight'];


    chartJSNodeCanvas = new ChartJSNodeCanvas({ width, height }); 
        
    const result = await chartJSNodeCanvas.renderToBuffer(chartBody);
    return res.end(result);
```

**PS.: Generating Charts on Server Side is a little difficult. So if there is a better solution, less memory wasting and FREE, it would help a lot.**

Comment: Perhaps you need to reuse the canvas instead of creating new ones https://github.com/SeanSobey/ChartjsNodeCanvas#memory-management

Comment: @BenTaber, was exactly it!